# Why is this statement "obvious" about embedded submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I've looked at many texts on rectifiable sets and I continue to see assertions that the following statement is in some sense obvious:

> Suppose that $N \subset \mathbf{R}^{n +k }$ is a $n$-dimensional $C^1$ submanifold. Then $N \subset N_0 \cup \cup_{j=1}^\infty F_j(\mathbf{R}^n)$, where $F_j: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^{n+k}$ are Lipschitz maps and $N_0$ is a set of $\mathcal{H}^n$-measure zero.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation of this statement, directly from the definition of an $n$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold, i.e.

> $N \subset \mathbf{R}^{n +k }$ is a $n$-dimensional $C^1$ submanifold provided that for each $x \in N$, there are opens $V \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ and $W \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+k}$ an injective $C^1$ map $\psi: V \to W$ such that $x \in \psi(V) = W \cap N$. Furthermore, $D\psi$ should be full rank (rank $n$) on $V$, and the inverse map $\varphi: \psi(V) \to V$ should be continuous.

Comment: Ok. I would very much appreciate the details if you have the time @Federico!

Comment: You seem be mislead a bit here. It seems you came across the definition of $n$- rectifiable sets and some remark saying that embedded $C^1$ manifolds are (obvious) examples. For an embedded $C^1$ manifold you can replace Lipshitz by $C^1$ and you can omit the set of measure zero altogether. Just cover $M$ by $C^1$ charts (which you can do by the definition), find a reason that you can do with countably many of them (this you should do yourself) and then note that things are even easier than necessary by observing that you only need to verify $N\subset \dots$, not $N= \dots$.